# WooCommerce shipping cost per product - 1 price for 1 country and another for rest

Tags: woocommerce

So I have to get shipping set up for a woocommerce store.

There needs to be a set price of €3.50 for nearly all items shipped to Ireland and these will be €13 if shipped internationally.

The thing is there is also a bundle and the shipping for that is €10.50 to Ireland and €20 internally.

Could someone point me in a direction on how I can do this. I tried a free per product shipping plugin which handles everything apart from the different cost for international shipping. Is there a plugin that you can enter a shipping cost per product for a list of regions then have a rest of world option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this is possible in WooCommerce out of the box. I didn't realise that when setting up shipping zones you can enter for example €3.50 x [qty] and that sets a per product shipping fee. It lets you define a rest of the world rate too.